# Empty results for json2csv node module

Tags: node.js

I am having a problem using the json2csv node module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv). This is my code:

```
var fields = ['originCountry', 'destinationCountry', 'avgNationalTuitionFee'];
    var outputResult = [
     {
      "outputOriginCountry" : "Denmakr", //origin,
      "outputDestinationCountry" : "Germany", //destination,
      "outputAvgTuitionFee" : "10000"
     },
     {
      "outputOriginCountry" : "Italy", //origin,
      "outputDestinationCountry" : "Spain", //destination,
      "outputAvgTuitionFee" : "5000"
     }
    ];

    var csv = json2csv({ data: outputResult, fields: fields });
    console.log("Csv file contains " + csv)

    fs.writeFile('analysis-output.csv', csv, function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('file saved');
    });
```

The problem is that the output is empty, as you can see in the picture:
[image]

However, I don’t know what the problem is. Do you have any clues?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your fields don't match your `outputResult` property names.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @BenFortune, it worked!